# How to do a 301 redirect in .htaccess from several addresses which user enter to one end address?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For example, the end address is `https://www.example.com`

When user enter such variants of address:

- `example.com`
- `example.com/index.php`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com/index.php`
- `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com/index.php`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://example.com/index.php`

from all of that addresses must be one 301 redirect to `https://www.example.com`, not several consecutive:

- `example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`
- `example.com/index.php` -> `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

and so on.

Comment: What about the URL-path? Do you wish to preserve the URL-path (except for `index.php`)? In the examples you posted there is no URL-path at all (except for `index.php` which you want to discard) and you are redirecting everything to the document root?

Comment: Do you have any other domains that point to the same hosting account? Or do you only have `example.com`?

Comment: https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash

Answer (score 1):

Several of your URL examples actually represent the same URL. eg. `http://www.example.com` and `www.example.com` (the browser naturally defaults to HTTP).

Despite listing many "different" URLs, there are just 3 criteria you want to satisfy:

- Remove `index.php` from the start of the URL-path.
- Redirect non-www to www
- Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

We need to make a couple of assumptions since this is missing from your question:

- You want to preserve any URL-path (and query string).
- The SSL cert is installed directly on your application server and you are not using an SSL proxy. This determines how you check whether the request is already HTTPS or not.

#### Separate rules / 1 redirect

Providing you redirect to the same canonical scheme+hostname, you don't necessarily need to reduce this to a single rule - there will still be at most 1 redirect.

Try the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "index.php"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

# non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You should first test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues, since 301s are persistently cached by the browser by default.

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable may or may not be necessary, depending on whether you are routing all requests through a front-controller (ie. internally rewriting to `index.php`) - a common design pattern.

The non-www to www redirect could arguably be "simplified" if we know you only have one domain and no subdomains. ie. we could simply check for not-www (`!^www\.`) instead of explicitly checking the domain apex (`^example\.com`).

#### Single rule / 1 redirect

These could be reduced into a single rule if you wanted (still just 1 redirect), but there is no real benefit in doing so (in fact, it may be harder to read):

```
# Canonicalise "index.php" / HTTPS / www
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|(.*))$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

#### Single "generic" rule / 1 redirect

If you only have a single domain and no subdomains then you could implement an entirely generic version, for example:

```
# Canonicalise "index.php" / HTTPS / www - Generic version
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+?)\.?$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|(.*))$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this isn't necessarily any "better" than the first version I posted above and is arguably more prone to error. Although it does demonstrate some useful principles in the use of mod_rewrite and regex.